# Why Django test returns bad status code?

Tags: python, django, http

I'm testing my Django API and I have a simple test that looks like this:

```
def test_owner_is_refused_when_not_logged(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/api2/get_owner_infos')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 401)
```

However, the test fails because the status code in the test is 301 so I get a `AssertionError: 301 != 401` error.

Yet, when I do `http://my-local-server/api2/get_owner_infos` I get a 401 HTTP response.

What's wrong with my test?
Thanks.

Comment: please post your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resp = self.client.get('/api2/get_owner_infos/')
```

pls check where the url endswith '/'

Comment: Clever! Thanks a lot :) (I'll accept the answer as soon as I can)